# Postman to inhereit authorization, headers, and pre-request scripts for clicked links

Tags: postman

If I send a request from a collection that uses Collection level authorization (and also pre-request scripts), and then click on a REST link in the response body, Postman does not seem to copy over the Authorization, Headers, or Pre-request scripts. Instead, it states:

> This request is not inheriting any authorization helper at the moment. Save it in a collection to use the parent's authorization helper.

Of course, the links are often temporary in nature, such as `/api/foos/123/`, and it would not make sense to save this request in the collection.

It looks like this feature has been [requested](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4546), but not prioritized.

In the meantime, are there any workaround that can minimize the number of clicks required to include at least the headers on clicked links?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it, Settings --> General

**Reference :** https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/launching_postman/settings

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I haven't really gotten back a response on this, Is this what you've been looking for ? If not, I'd be pleased to to dig in more detail and learn for myself too !